# How to use a reference (ArduinoUploader) in c#, code does not match

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, arduino

I have made a nice Serial reader App to read the data from my Arduino, the App works great and i found a resource library "sorry i don't know the correct term is it 'Reference'" called ArduinoSketchUploader which can be found here [ArduinoSketchUploader](https://github.com/christophediericx/ArduinoSketchUploader), and i followed the steps using the NuGet manager in Visual studio and a message says its added to my project and is listed under references but my App is created with the Visual studio Form and the only window i have is From1.vb to which i am sure that i should not place the function provided.

How do i use the ArduinoSketchUploader library with my app, for now i just want to run the simple function provided. Agin the code syntax does not match how do i call this function below with a visual studio Form App I see it in my Apps reference listed and object manager but am unsure who to start the upload i see nothing to invoke ??

The link [library link](https://github.com/christophediericx/ArduinoSketchUploader) says to call this function to start the upload but if i paste the function in my Public class from1 the entire function gets errors as the syntax does not match i.e. var upload. where do i call or paste this function and call it with a button click from my form ??

```
var uploader = new ArduinoSketchUploader(
new ArduinoSketchUploaderOptions()
{
    FileName = @"C:\MyHexFiles\UnoHexFile.ino.hex",
    PortName = "COM3",
    ArduinoModel = ArduinoModel.UnoR3
});

uploader.UploadSketch();
```

Heres what the .vb code looks like, I just included Class and the first function

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim myPort As Array
    Delegate Sub setTextCallBack(ByVal [text] As String)
    Dim SerialAutoScoll, SerialNewLine, startSearch, startSearchBetween, startSearchAfter As Boolean
    Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        portComboBox.Items.AddRange(myPort)
        sendButton.Enabled = False
        closeButton.Enabled = False
        SearchButton.Enabled = False
        ClearSearchButton.Enabled = False
        baudRateComboBox.SelectedIndex = 11
        portComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub
```

Comment: which kind of intellisense or compilation error do you get? the package manager should have added the reference for you, maybe you're just missing a `using` statement (similar to `Imports` in VB)?

Comment: Well I see it under references and object manager but thats it, how to i call the "var uploader" to start the upload ? This is my first time using the package manager - a library in Visual studio

Comment: I don't get which problem prevents you from compiling or executing the code. the last line in your C# code sample is the call to start the upload.

Comment: I cant see that C# code any where just the code in the .vb file which is the Public class form1, the var uploader = new ArduinoSketchUploader( i just copied from the link i provided they say to use that function to start the upload but i cant paste the var uploader = new ArduinoSketchUploader( function in my public lass form1 i get errors all over

Comment: uhh. now I'm really confused. is it the wrong project type altogether? do you need a C#.NET console or library or web project, and what you have is a VB.NET project?

Comment: Yes i think so, thats what i am unsure about i have made a form and it let me add this library but can i use it ??? My code looks a different format, again im new to c# and VB and i am unsure if i made a .NET code or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a VB.NET project, but want to write code in C#. Visual Studio does not support mixing languages *inside the same project*. It is possible to mix projects of different framework languages in a solution though.

You probably want to create a project from one of Visual Studio's C# templates, like a C# Console Project, add the nuget package there, then you can continue writing code in the C# language.